# import.io crawler won't load a standard php page

Tags: import.io

I can't get import.io to load this standard page?
https://www.motoshopfinder.com/moto-shops-in-AL.php

I'm not sure if it's because it's behind a https URL but the certificate is invalid or what.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: It works on my side, could you describe the problem a bit more? What steps are you taking to get to your result?

Comment: Well I got it to run but then for some reason after a few times the site starts redirecting to some vapeshop website. Is this detecting a scraper and redirecting or is there a virus on that site?>